# How to Translate Validation Constraint Messages

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

That is my first concern here.

```
# config/validator/validation.yaml
App\Usecase\GetEntity\GetEntityRequest:
properties:
  date:
    - Date:
        message: 'get.date.msg'
```

How can I replace the placeholder "**get.date.msg**" with the right error msg?

The official documentation does not help:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/translations.html

Where exactly should the translation file be?
In "**config/translations**" or in "**config/validator/translations**"? 
Maybe in "**root/translations**"?^^

In the end, I tried everything. 
The output is never translated, every time the place holder "**get.date.msg**" is the output.

Do I need a Symfony translations package for this?

Answer (score 0):

The constraint messages must be in the file `app/Resources/translations/validators.en.yml` (maybe depends on your symfony version). Tries to put a validators.en.yml in the same place you have your messages.en.yml file.